# Generating a modal jQuery partial view with MVC4 does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I like the way MVC4 manage the new logon screen: it is possible to have a modal dialog showed.

[image]

I tried to reproduce the same behavior in the same solution for another view. But it doesn't work because **Request.QueryString["content"]** is null. I don't know why. In fact, there is an action method called ContextDependentView (generated by the MVC template) where the trick occurred. Here it is:

```
    private ActionResult ContextDependentView()
    {
        string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        if (Request.QueryString["content"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.FormAction = "Json" + actionName;
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.FormAction = actionName;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

If the value of **Request.QueryString["content"]** is not null then we display a partial view (modal jQuery) otherwise it is a classic view.

Can someone help me understand why this is not working?

PS: another thread already exists but without any solution.

Comment: follow the instructions on this link to fix your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763013/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-dialogs

Answer (score 2):

The login and register links are bound to a click handler in AjaxLogin.js which then adds content=1 in loadAndShowDialog