# ASP.NET MVC 4 JQuery Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to modify the javascript from an ASP.NET MVC 4 template website so that the dialogs that comes with the template to login/register actions could be used in any link that had an ".ajax-link" class in my code. So I did some changes in AjaxLogin.js that now looks like this:

```
//...

$('.ajax-link').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        var link = $(this),
            url = link.attr('href');

        var separator = url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?';

        $.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
        .done(function (content) {

            var dialog = $('<div class="modal-popup"">' + content + '</div>')
                .hide() // Hide the dialog for now so we prevent flicker
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .filter('div') // Filter for the div tag only, script tags could surface
                .dialog({ // Create the jQuery UI dialog
                    dialogClass: 'fi-dialog',
                    title: link.data('dialog-title'),
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    width: link.data('dialog-width') || 600,
                    beforeClose: function () { resetForm($(this).find('form')); }
                })
                .find('form') // Attach logic on forms
                    .submit(formSubmitHandler)
                .end();

            dialog.dialog('open');
        });

        // Prevent the normal behavior since we use a dialog
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

//...
```

And then I add the attribute class="ajax-link" in all the links I want to be shown in an jQuery dialog.

But it's not working. Actually the dialog opens only to the FIRST link I click inside the page, and after I close the dialog I can click in any other link that it won't appear. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: the old way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 4):

Actually you only need 2 very slight modifications to the `AjaxLogin.js` script to make this work.

The first modification is towards the end of the file where you have an array of selectors. All you have to do is add your `.ajax-link` selector:

```
// List of link ids to have an ajax dialog
var links = ['#loginLink', '#registerLink', '.ajax-link'];
```

and the second modification is inside the `resetForm` function in order to add a check if there's a form before attempting to reset it. Because if there isn't a form inside the partial you are rendering you will get an error when you attempt to close the dialog:

```
var resetForm = function ($form) {
    // make sure that there's a form before attempting to reset its elements
    if ($form.length < 1) {
        // No form inside the partial => we have nothing more to do here
        return;
    }

    // We reset the form so we make sure unobtrusive errors get cleared out.
    $form[0].reset();

    getValidationSummaryErrors($form)
        .removeClass('validation-summary-errors')
        .addClass('validation-summary-valid')
};
```

Now you can have:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Foo", 
    "foo", 
    null, 
    new { @class = "ajax-link", data_dialog_title = "hello" }
)
```

with a corresponding action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // return a PartialView or whatever you want to popup in the dialog
    return Content("hello world from a jQuery Dialog");
}
```

and it will show the result of the Foo action inside a dialog, exactly the same way it does for the `LogOn` and `Register` actions.

Comment: it worked! Thanks! Sort of. I don't know if it should be another question, but now it opens a dialog everytime I click in na link, but it always shows the same content, even if I click in another link, as if it's caching the content of the first dialog it opens and don't refresh it everytime I click in a another link. I`m missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ajax-link').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        var link = $(this),
            url = link.attr('href');

        var separator = url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?';

         //clear all cashed dialog form
        $("div.modal-popup").remove();
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var UIDialogId = 0;

            $('.UIDialogOpen').live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                UIDialogId++;

                $('<div/>', {
                    'id': $(this).attr('data-dialog-id') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-id') : 'UIDialog' + UIDialogId,
                    'class': 'UIDialog'
                }).appendTo('body').dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr('data-dialog-title') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-title') : 'Message',
                    position: ['center', 'center'],
                    modal: true, resizable: false, zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                    minWidth: $(this).attr('data-dialog-minwidth') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-minwidth') : '300px',
                    minHeight: $(this).attr('data-dialog-minheight') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-minheight') : '300px',
                    maxWidth: $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxwidth') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxwidth') : '300px',
                    maxHeight: $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxheight') !== undefined ? $(this).attr('data-dialog-maxheight') : '300px',
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                })
                //.load(this.href);

                //Or   //Use .load(this.href); and comment or delete below append line.

                .append('<h1>Hi.. This is Testing </h1> <input type="button" class="UIDialogCancel" value="Cancel" /> <input type="button" class="UIDialogClose" value="Close" />');


                $('.UIDialogClose, .UIDialogCancel').live('click', function (e) {
                    var obj = $(this)
                    e.preventDefault();
                    obj.parents('.UIDialog').dialog('close');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-atcX8smV6wA/T5ULj6LU4fI/AAAAAAAAAFg/oK08hPLOmWI/s1600/between.png"
        class="UIDialogOpen" data-id="bloger">Bloger</a>
    <br />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkName", "MethodeName", "ControllerName", new { Id =2
        }, new { @class = "UIDialogOpen", data_dialog_title = "UI Dialog Message" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkName", "MethodeName", "ControllerName", null, new {
        @class = "UIDialogOpen", data_dialog_title = "UI Dialog MEssage" })
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```